# Angular code executed on server or client side

Tags: angularjs, angular, asp.net-core-2.0

Look at this very basic typescript angular file. It is a very basic component

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";

@Component({
    selector: 'tagcomposant1',
    templateUrl: './composant1.component.html'
})

export class Composant1Component {    
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log("ngOnInit");
        alert('ngOnInit');
    }

    btn_click() {
        console.log("btn_click");
        alert("btn_click");
    }
}
```

Here is the html file:

```html
<button (click)="btn_click()">test</button>
```

I do not understand if `ngOnInit()` and `btn_click()` are runned on server side or in the browser.
I can see some log messages in the server console. And some alerts in the browser. So i do not understand.

I am working on an asp.net core 2 mvc angular project

Thanks

Comment: Angular is client-side. Everything is run by the browser.

Comment: @Adrien use the "close" function for that, and indicate the duplicate's URL

Comment: @JeremyThille, when you flag a question for duplicate, it automatically generates this comment.

Comment: Yes, but when you write this comment, it does not flag the question as duplicate. That was my point. You didn't flag it as duplicate, you wrote the comment. I did flag is as duplicate, and my vote is the only one recorded.

Comment: @JeremyThille No, I didn't write the comment. I flagged and the comment was automatically generated.

Comment: Uh? So, how come there's only one recorded vote? Is that a bug or something?

Comment: "You have already raised a recommended closure flag" on my side, pretty clear to me. Maybe a bug yeah.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular code is run client-side on the web browser. Angular code is written in Typescript that is then transpiled in Javascript and this javascript code is ran on the browser of the client.

The messages you see server-side are communicated by the client application to the server via HTTP calls.

More details about Angular architecture here: https://angular.io/guide/architecture

Answer (score 0):

It's of course client side. Is your component visible in the browser?